Tabbing: \' and \`
As far as I have understood, \' and \` have something to do with alignment in tabbing environments. But what I find through google is rather cryptic, and my experiment
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{tabbing}
        fffffffffff \= ffffffffff \= asdf\\
         \> right\' left \\
         \> r\'
    \end{tabbing}
\end{document}

looks odd, because the t from right is not directly under the f in the line above. What does \' (and \`) do precisely?

set \taggingsep=0pt (default is 5pt). And do not ignore spaces, either remove the one between f and \= or add one after right.

@UlrikeFischer Please make this an answer to get the question off the unanswered list.
